# How to Put Time Series Values as Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a simple problem but I am not sure how to make it work.

I have a dataset, which records temperatures of devices:

```
Device_ID Temperature Label
1           50          0
1           40          0
2           34          0
1           78          0
2           66          1
3           88          0
1           12          0
2           33          0
3           91          0
```

Devices can send temperature at any time. The above dataset is already sorted by time.

What I want to do?

> Classify devices based on their temperature pattern.

I already have the labels for the dataset, labels indicate whether the devices went bad after a measurement (1 means that after this measurement the device went bad, 0 means its okay).

If the device goes bad, it's label is always bad now -> i.e. I will only need time series values upto that point. The device is now labelled bad and the future measurements don't matter.

So, I want to construct the classification dataset as:

```
Device_ID  T1  T2 T3 T4 ... Tn Label

1          50 40 78 ...          0
2          34 66 .....           1 (33 measurement now does not matter)
```

So, my question is **how do I convert these time series values in the rows to columns in Pandas?** How to do this task **efficiently**?

I can use Pivot, but Pivot works only for Categorical variables.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you determine the overall label for each device?

Comment: @coldspeed I have two choices: 1. if the device goes bad, it's label is always bad now. 2. if after going bad the device recovers (i.e. the label again becomes 0), then I can construct another datapoint in my final dataset for the same device, but now with a different label. I can work with any of the two options. If I get solution to 1, I am sure I can do the 2nd one myself.

Comment: @coldspeed a working solution would be: If the device goes bad, it's label is always bad now -> i.e. I will only need time series values upto that point. The device is now labelled bad and the future measurements don't matter.

Comment: make the device a categorical, or object type.. 
dataset.device = detaset.devise.astype('category')